# Objective-C multi threading - Why does my code produce a deadlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, deadlock

I am using the following code to prevent a background task from being started twice. Why does this code block?

```
- (void)doBackgroundTask {
    NSLog(@"Before LOCK: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    // lockObject is created once in init
    @synchronized(lockObject) {
        if (taskActive)
            taskCanceller.shouldCancel = true;

        while (taskActive) {
           // NOOP: Busy waiting
           //NSLog(@"Busy waiting: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        }

        taskActive = true;
        taskCanceller = [[AsyncTaskCanceller alloc] init];
    }

    NSLog(@"After LOCK: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{        
        NSLog(@"AsyncStart: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        AsyncTaskCanceller *canceller = taskCanceller;
        [self loadDataAsync:canceller];

        NSLog(@"Setting taskActive to FALSE: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        taskActive = false;
        NSLog(@"taskActive == FALSE: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

        if (canceller.shouldCancel == false) {
            NSLog(@"Complete: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Completed: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
                ...
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Canceled: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        }

        NSLog(@"AsyncComplete: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    }); 

    NSLog(@"SyncComplete: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
}
```

The code produces the following output:

```
Before LOCK:                 <NSThread: 0x1706663c0>{number = 5, name = (null)}
After LOCK:                  <NSThread: 0x1706663c0>{number = 5, name = (null)}
SyncComplete:                <NSThread: 0x1706663c0>{number = 5, name = (null)}
AsyncStart:                  <NSThread: 0x174c75d00>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Before LOCK:                 <NSThread: 0x1706663c0>{number = 5, name = (null)}
Setting taskActive to FALSE: <NSThread: 0x174c75d00>{number = 7, name = (null)}
taskActive == FALSE:         <NSThread: 0x174c75d00>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Canceled:                    <NSThread: 0x174c75d00>{number = 7, name = (null)}
AsyncComplete:               <NSThread: 0x174c75d00>{number = 7, name = (null)}
```

Which can be translated to:

- **Thread 5** enters the method
- **Thread 5** gets the LOCK and check if the Task is running. This is not the case, so it is started in a background thread
- **Thread 5** exits the method
- Task is performed in **Thread 7**
- **Thread 5** enters the method again and gets the LOCK. Since Task is running, it switches to busy waiting until `taskActive` is set to false
- **Thread 7** sets `taskActive = false`
- **Thread 7** finishes

After Thread 7 set `taskActive`back to `false` the `while` loop should end, shouldn't it? **Why does it not?**

**Even more strange:** If I active the `NSLog` statement within the busy waiting `while` loop everything works as expected.

Comment: Is `taskActive` marked as volatile?

Comment: FYI, unless your task is going to be *very* short (as in microseconds, *maybe* milliseconds), busy waiting is a bad idea.  It keeps a CPU core at 100%, which will drain the battery very fast.

Comment: @dan volatile was the correct solution :-) Do you create an answer that I can accept? NobodyNada You are right, but in this special case the task is really short.

Comment: I'm not sure that volatile make sense here because `taskActive` is instance variable.

Comment: Would be nice to see assembler code produced by compiler.